# prettyphotto ie7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, prettyphoto

I get an error in IE7 with Prettyphoto:

I have a simple a tag, if I place it directly in the dom then it works, but if I create it with jquery and append in the dom than I get an error.

```
<a href="#inline-1" data-rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]"><img src="01.jpg" width="120" height="68" alt=""/></a>
```

This example works:
    [example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/g47cV/3/)
(a tag is placed directly in dom)

This example doesnt works:
    [example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/QYXp6/3/)
(a tag is created with jquery and appended in dom)

The error is:
"Image could not be loaded. Make sure the path is correct and the image exist."

Comment: Well I don't have IE7 but IE9, and I'm not seeing any missing image, even in compatibility mode.

Comment: `src="01.jpg"` Are you sure that's not your problem? There's no path leading up to the filename, unlike both the examples which you linked to.

Comment: This is just an example. I had to post some 'relevant' code for a stackoverflow to accept my question. Look in the jsfiddle, there is a real link.

Comment: Yes, I see the real link and am having no issues at all with it, However again I'm using IE9, not 7.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I also dont have 'real' IE7, but I am using browser mode in developer tools. And this is the example from prettyphoto site itself (scroll down to Inline content): http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto And this works like that.

Comment: If I knew more about web development I'd dig deeper, but it's a fairly unfamiliar subject as I'm more familiar with windows applications.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.In general you need to fire prettyPhoto after DOM is recreated again:

```
            //Some Javascript code creates DOM in here and then you will fire prettyPhoto even again to update and apply on new created DOM elements
            $("area[rel^='popUp']").prettyPhoto(); 
            $(".popUpWindow:first a[rel^='popUp']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal',theme:'facebook',autoplay_slideshow: false,social_tools: false});
            $(".popUpWindow:gt(0) a[rel^='popUp']").prettyPhoto({animation_speed:'normal',theme:'facebook',autoplay_slideshow: false,social_tools: false});
```